# Split a string into a vector of single character strings

Tags: r, string

I have a string like `"abcde"` and want it split into a vector like

```
> c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

I found one way that I'll post as an answer but I am hoping someone else has a simpler way to do this, either in base R or using a package.

Comment: `strsplit("abcde", "")` returns a list. Then you can do `unlist(...)`.

Answer (score 5):

Using the stringr package:

```
library(stringr)
as.vector(str_split_fixed(x, pattern = "", n = nchar(x)))
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

`str_split_fixed` produces a matrix that has to be coerced into a vector.

Comment: stringr 1.5.0 introduced `str_split_1()`, which splits a single string into a character vector